# Cannot access zxing jar in android studio

Tags: android, zxing

I've added zxing core prebuilt jar to my Android studio project. However, I am unable to access any of the classes. If I do `com.google.zxing` it doesn't recognize the import nor any other package. The error I receive is `Cannot resolve symbol zxing`. I did add it as a dependency to my project, so I'm not sure what is going on. zxing core is added as another module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first time I tried this, I imported the core files with javadoc. I'm not sure if this was the problem. I tried again importing the core jar, except this time without the javadocs. I am able to access the classes now.